# Boost.Filesystem-like Library for D

Tags: iterator, filesystems, d, tree-traversal

Has anybody written a D library similar to Boost.Filesystem providing iterators/ranges that can do for example file system directory tree traversal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`dirEntries` from `std.file`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.dirEntries) returns a range that enumerates files and directories, optionally under subdirectories as well.

Comment: Great! BTW: Interesting that the return value is auto! Is there some useful deduction/reduction of return type here?

Comment: It's just a `DirIterator`, but it's more of an implementation detail as the type is not documented.